# Как сделать пагинацию в парсере на Python?

Tags: python, парсер, пагинация

Я начинаю изучать парсинг на Python.Я написал парсер,который парсит Stopgame.ru,но у меня не получается сделать пагинацию.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
        "accept": "* / *",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.97 Safari/537.36"
    }

url = "https://stopgame.ru/topgames?p="

response = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
game_name = soup.find_all("div", class_="caption caption-bold")


for games_name in game_name:
    games_name = games_name.find("a")

    print(games_name.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если под пагинацией вы имеете ввиду переход на следующие страницы и парсинг информации оттуда, то можно сделать цикл, который на каждой итерации будет к концу ссылки страницы добавлять соответствующий номер страницы.
Открыв ссылку можно увидеть, что страниц в общем 26. Это кол-во итераций

```
for i in range(1, 27):
    url = "https://stopgame.ru/topgames?p={}".format(i)

    response = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    game_name = soup.find_all("div", class_="caption caption-bold")

    for games_name in game_name:
        games_name = games_name.find("a")
        print(games_name.text)
```